# allow duplicate value for parameters

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I want my parameter to have 2 possible values (Value_1, Value_2) but 3 possible labels (Label_1, Label_2, Label_3), i.e:

Label_1 Value_1

Label_2 Value_2

Label_3 Value_1

If I select Label_3 in the parameter drop down menu, SSRS will change it automatically to Label_1 (since Label_3 and Label_1 have the same value). Is there a way to prevent it?

Comment: Why did you even want to have two labels with same value ?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that there is no way for you to do what you are asking. When you select "Label_3" what you are actually doing in the background is setting the parameter value to "Value_1". The displayed label for the parameter is then updated, based on the value, but it will display the first match which is "Label_1". If both Label_1 and Label_3 have the same value, then they are functionally indistinguishable from one another so you can combine them into a single option e.g. "Label_1 / Label_3".